# How to pass extra argument when creating object that uses ** (double star) syntax in python?

Tags: python, function, object, arguments

How do I pass an extra argument "`page_name`" when creating `NotebookPage` object below? I get the error below:

```
class NotebookPage(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)


NotebookPage(self, name='NotebookPage0', page_name=page)


TypeError: 'page_name' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

I need to pass `page_name` argument when creating `NotebookPage` object. But since `page_name` is not a valid argument of `wx.Panel`, I get that error.

Comment: for consistency with python naming, you should use `kwarg` instead of `kwargs`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should remove additional argument from `kwargs` before calling `__init__`. For example with dict [`pop`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict.pop#dict.pop) method:

```
class NotebookPage(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        page_name = kwargs.pop('page_name', None)
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        if page_name:
            # somehow using page_name here
```

Comment: Thanks, is this the conventionally used method in such circumstances?

Comment: @alwbtc yes, i think so

Answer (score 4):

In Python 3.x, you can simply mention the explicit kwarg before the other ones, [like this](http://ideone.com/IWHLGV):

```
class NotebookPage(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, *args, page_name, **kwargs):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        print(page_name)
```

In older (2.x) versions of Python, this only works if there are no variable argument lists (`*args`).

Answer (score 1):

You probably are having problem about *inherited class initialization*. You are trying to pass arguments that inherited class initialization can not handle. That happens generally when inherited class `__init__` do not accept `*args`, and/or `**kwargs` and you try to pass an argument that do not defined in inherited class `__init__` arguments

Lets have two classes with one inherited the other

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, x, y=None):
        pass


class B(A):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        page_num = kwargs.get('page_num')
        A.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

something = B(x=1, page_num=2)
```

When we create an instance `something`, it will call `B.__init__`. Since `B` accepts positional and named arguments, there is no problem in here. Then it will call `A.__init__` and pass arguments `x=1, page_num=2`. `A.__init__` have argument `x`, but have neither any positional nor any named arguments to handle `page_num`. So it raises an error.

If inherited class do accept only *pre-defined* arguments, then you must either remove undefined arguments from your wildcard arguments (`*args` and `**kwargs`) with `kwargs.pop` and `args.remove` or get related parameters from them with `kwargs.get` or `args[<index>]` and pass them to inherited `__init__`